# Adding views to TableLayout inside a fragment during runtime

Tags: android, user-interface, android-fragments

I've looked through the similar questions and not yet found an answer. I will eventually be adding each of my `View`s after acquiring data from a SQL db, but for now, I am simply trying to add a set of views so I can get my layout working. I have a main activity with a fragment manager that gets my tabs flowing and loading just fine, so I don't think I need to provide that code here.

Here is the code for the fragment:

```
public class EconFragment extends Fragment {

private ViewGroup container;


public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    populateQuestions(container, inflater);
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.econfragment, container, false);

}


public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    container.removeAllViews();
}

private void populateQuestions(ViewGroup v, LayoutInflater inflater) {
    container = v;
    int count = 10;
    int runner = 0;


    while (runner < count) {
    View question = inflater.inflate(R.layout.question, null);
    question.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    container.addView(question, runner);
    runner++;
    }
}
}
```

So while this should populate in more than one Question.xml View into the container, I only have one show up. It's interesting to note that I can observe the delay as runner increases up to count, but again, only one question view shows up. When I change things up, I get a lot of null pointers around my `TableLayout`, so I have removed that portion.

Ultimately, `EconFragment`'s xml has a Table Layout with a `ScrollView` which has another `TableLayout`, questionContainer.

**I had hoped originally to add each question view as a row in `questionContainer`, but that's giving me all sorts of trouble. I posit that it's somewhat related to calling `populateQuestions()` prior to the return statement in `onCreateView()`?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I solved the problem. It doesn't implement the SQL dB access that I desire, it just has a filler while loop and a dummy array of strings to make the Table Rows. I'm almost done implementing the login/register via SQL dB, and as soon as that's done, populating these tablerow's via SQL shouldn't be a big problem.

```
public class EconFragment extends Fragment {


    private TableLayout questionContainer;
    static int pos = 0;
    private String[] titles = {"The first title ", "hallo1","hallo2", "hallo3",
            "hallo4", "hallo5","hallo6", "hallo7","hallo8", "hallo9"};

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d("Econ", "onCreateView");

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.econfragment, container, false);
    }

    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();


        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().
        getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        questionContainer = (TableLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.questionContainer);



        //these lines are my first attempt to try and get the questions to repopulate after returning
        //from pressing back - as of yet, they don't repopulate the screen:
        //View econFragment = inflater.inflate(R.layout.econfragment, null);
        //container.addView(econFragment);

        int leftMargin=5;
        int topMargin=5;
        int rightMargin=5;
        int bottomMargin=5;
        while (pos < 10) {
        View question = inflater.inflate(R.layout.question, null);
        question.setId(pos);
        TextView title = (TextView) question.findViewById(R.id.questionTextView);
        title.setText(titles[pos]);
        Button charts = (Button) question.findViewById(R.id.chartsButton);
        charts.setId(pos);
        charts.setOnClickListener(chartsListener);
        TableRow tr = (TableRow) question;
        TableLayout.LayoutParams trParams = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        trParams.setMargins(leftMargin, topMargin, rightMargin, bottomMargin);
        tr.setLayoutParams(trParams);

        questionContainer.addView(tr);
        pos++;
        }
        Log.d("Econ", "onResume");
    }
```